# Change the assembly language of IDA 5.0

Tags: ida

Is it possible to set the assembly language to AT&T syntax for IDA 5.0?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Ida Pro 5.0 have only intel and tasm syntax

Comment: Still seems true in IDA Pro 7.0... too bad for those of us who prefer AT&T.